# Programmatically get list of standard headers supported in fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am looking to get list of all Headers supported or available in browser fetch. There should be some place/API which browsers provide to get the list. The list by MDN is [published here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). This also provides reference to wiki page for [list of headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Is there any API using which we can get this list in Javascript/browser page?
Or if there is any library like which includes this list and can be referenced from there, so our code keeps updated.